# Get random text variable from tkinter button - python

Tags: python, tkinter

The title might be a little confusing, so i will describe my question more.

I making a little program that will assist me with studying Chinese, just for myself. This will aid me with coding and in same time with studying.

I encounter a problem with getting the text variable from my button, without function the code work like wanted. But when trying to get random text that shown on the button it cause me a problem, because text doesn't come. All i need it, when button is pressed function check if input is the same as character and give correct/incorrect notice.

I little new to coding, so it can be simple matter, but still appreciate any help.

The code:

```
#========== Imports ===========#

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import random

#========== Parameters ==========#

CN = Tk()
CN.title("Chinese Test")
CNW = ["爱","八","爸爸","杯子","北京","本","不客气","不","菜","茶","吃","出租车","打电话",
       "大","的","点","电脑","电视","电影","东西","都","读","对不起","多","多少","儿子",
       "二","饭店","飞机","分钟","高兴","个","工作","汉语","好","号","喝","和","很","后面","回","会","几","家","叫","今天"]
Cword = ""
Cent = StringVar()


def butPress():
    global Cword
    if (B0.text==Cword): #wrong way to get text
        messageText = "Correct"
    else:
        messageText = "Incorrect"

CNEntry = Entry(CN,textvariable = Cent).grid(row = 0, column = 1, columnspan = 8)

B0 = Button(CN, text = random.choice(CNW),command = lambda:butPress,bd = 3, width = 5, height = 3).grid(row = 6, column = 4, padx = 10, pady = 10)

#========== Pack ==========#

CN.mainloop(  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things.
First of all, `command = lambda:butPress` doesn't work. Use `command = butPress`. You should only use a lambda when you need to pass parameters (e.g. `command = lambda:butPress(parameter)`), which you don't.

Then there's `B0.text`. Because you do

```
B0 = Button(...).grid(...)
```

`B0` is `None`, because that is what `grid()` returns. Change it to

```
B0 = Button(...)
B0.grid(...)
```

This way `B0` is a `Button` object. To get the current text of it you can't use `B0.text`, you have to use `B0['text']`.

You then compare the text to `Cword`, which is `''` and never changes. If you want to compare it to the entered text in the Entry use `CNEntry.get()` (after again putting `grid` on a separate line).

Comment: Thanks you very much, that help. Totally forgotten about those little things. Will test it out and improve, because for now it doesn't really work.